# How to resolve permission denied error in shelljs and child-process module in node js?

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process, shelljs

I am using shelljs module to execute a bash file in node for a server side program. I even tried child-process module to execute the bash file. In both cases I got permission denied error. I am using linux(ubuntu disto). Here is the code snippet.

```
var shell = require("shelljs");
var cp = require("child_process");
shell.exec('../scripts/test.sh');
cp.exec('../scripts/test.sh', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
console.log(stdout);
console.log(stderr);
if (error !== null) {
   console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
 }
});
```

Here is the file structure.

```
 |-Parent file
   |-routes
     --file containing the above javascript code
   |-scripts
     --test.sh
```

Here is the error.

```
/bin/sh: 1: ../scripts/test.sh: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: ../scripts/test.sh: Permission denied
 exec error: Error: Command failed: ../scripts/test.sh
/bin/sh: 1: ../scripts/test.sh: Permission denied
```

Can anyone suggest me why this error is occurring and how to resolve it? 
Note- I have not used any sudo commands in the test.sh . Just a simple echo command like echo "Hello World"

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `chmod +x ../scripts/test.sh` to give access to run the script file. If that fails, try to use Sudo to run the node script.

Comment: Ok thanks the chmod +x command worked.